# Add JAVA_HOME and JAVA_HOME/bin in your environment variable

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

I have extracted this from the book called

```
Rhomobile Beginner's Guide
Abhishek Nalwaya
Published Jul 2011
```

on `page 18` it says:

Add `JAVA_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME/bin` in your environment variable, PATH.

To add this in PATH click on Environment Variables in Advanced Tab of System Property.

Select Path in System variables and add `JAVA_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME/bin` to textbox and click Ok.

What should be the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will let you and other applications run Java tools without having to type the whole path.

I disagree about adding JAVA_HOME; I only have JAVA_HOME/bin in my PATH.

Tomcat requires that JAVA_HOME be set properly in order to operate; so do some other Java EE app servers.  (I believe WebLogic needs it.)

Answer (score 0):

The value should be the install directory for your JRE or JDK,

Browse your 'program files' folder for a java folder, should look something like:

C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.xx\

There will be a directory called bin inside it.